# Obtener un registro por medio de campos sin llaves

Tags: sql

Tengo una base de datos que no tiene llaves foráneas ni índices: fue creada hace muchos años, por lo que tiene campos en común con identificadores pero diferente nombre.

Necesito una consulta de 3 tablas en las cuales organizar información por medio de esos campos en común.

> Tabla 1 = CatCodigos
>
> Campos =  cod_tipo, cod_codigo , cod_Desc

> Tabla 2 =  Produccion
>
> Campos = pro_CT, pro_Fecha, pro_Turno, pro_Ord, pro_PartF, pro_Prod, pro_Tiempo

> Tabla 3 = Desperdicio
>
> Campos = des_CT, des_Fecha, des_Ord , des_Cant

Como pueden observar *des_CT* y *pro_CT* son campos en común y se usan como llaves primarias.

Necesito hacer una consulta que me traiga la siguiente información:

> pro_PartF, cod_Desc, pro_Prod, des_Cant, Produccion total (suma de ProdydesCant), pro_Tiempo

Tengo la siguiente query que me da toda la información excepto la suma de los desperdicios para esos números de parte y de orden.

```
SELECT Produccion.pro_PartF,CatCodigos.cod_Desc,  SUM(Produccion.pro_Prod) AS 'Produccion Neta',SUM(pro_Tiempo) AS 'Tiempo Trabajado'
FROM Produccion, CatCodigos
WHERE pro_PartF = cod_Codigo AND Produccion.pro_Fecha BETWEEN '01/16/2022'AND '01/31/2022' AND pro_CT = 106 
GROUP BY cod_Desc, pro_PartF
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agregar después del campo producción neta la cantidad de desperdicio y luego sumarla en el siguiente campo, pero no encuentro la forma.

Estoy realizando este reporte por medio de asp por lo que los campos fecha inicio, fecha fin y CT los seleccionare de un combo box, por eso en la consulta los dejé como FIJOS, ya después solo paso valores por medio de variables hacia la query. Por el momento me interesan esas fechas y CT = 106 para corroborar información.

Estoy tratando de migrar este reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando? ¿PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas claves foráneas para combinar tablas, las FK son restricciones que impiden registrar datos inexistentes. Si eso lo controlas de otra forma, no serían necesarias. De hecho hay sistemas que, por cuestiones de rendimiento, ni las implementan.

En tu consulta únicamente combinas dos de las tres tablas:

```
FROM Produccion, CatCodigos
```

Cuando deberías combinar las tres, pues el desperdicio lo registras en la tabla `Desperdicio`.

En vez de combinar con `,` te recomendaría utilizar `JOIN ON`, es mucho más eficiente.

Espero haberte aclarado algo. Si necesitas más ayuda, tendrías que decirme los campos que tienen en común esas tres tablas. Se vería rápidamente con unos datos de muestra cada una.

Comment: Gracacias por la respuesta, si efectivamente solo me he acercado a ese reporte con la consulta que comparti, no incluyo la tercera tabla por que no me da el resultado o falla la consulta.

Comment: Modifica la pregunta añadiendo tu nuevo intento con los campos que te he solicitado y, si no te funciona, completo la respuesta con la solución. Si así ya te ha servido: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)